# Json file is not accessible from another function in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, function, cypress

I am trying to access config data from a JSON file (in Cypress).
The code is working fine if I use one function:

```
workingFunction() {
var data;
cy.fixture('env/environments').then((readedData) => {
    data = readedData;
    cy.log(data.clientEnvironment.qa);
 });
}
```

Here is an example of my JSON file:

```
{
    "clientEnvironment": {
            "qa": "hardcode clients url here"
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

But if I try to split the logic into two functions (in one class) - it seems that I am not able to read the JSON file data from another function.

Here is my code:

```
readDataFunction(): any {
    let data;
    cy.fixture('env/environments').then((readedData) => {
    return data = readedData;
    });
}

secondFunction() {
    cy.log(this.readDataFunction());
}
```

The result here is an empty log.
Screenshot:
[image]